# iPhone SDK - Drawing to the view during a UINavigationController animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I currently have a standard `UINavigationController` based iPhone app, which I am having a problem with - and I'm currently in need of some advice.

I have a view which is pushed to the stack, and in the `ViewDidLoad` I am programmatically adding **96 subviews** (yeah, I guess that's a lot). This works fine for the most part, but when the view is pushed the animation is jerky. I suppose this is because it is drawing the subviews at the same time, but I'm not sure.

Does anyone have any experience with this? **Is there a way I can add these 96 subviews before the view is animated?**

Cheers,
Brett

Answer (score 0):

You cut put it in the loadView?
Or you could create a method called "addSubViews" in which you add the 96 subviews (wtf btw) and then do something like this:

```
NextViewController * nextViewController = [[NextViewController alloc] init];
[nextViewController addSubViews];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
[nextViewController release]; // Or not, if you are using ARC ;)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call your subview creator function in "**initWithNibName**" or any **init** function of your viewcontroller, other way, call your function before pushing that viewcontroller.
So [@Rick van der Linde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/739302/rick-van-der-linde) was right.